# Joomla: Multiple templates for different Articles

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

in Wordpress we can have different style or template for each posts.

I want to know how can I have something similar in Joomla 3. I need to have 3 different post style for articles. one of them has no sidebar and full width post layout. I know I can have post without sidebar for specific category which assign to the menu but I need to have this option in post submit article in backend because I need this feature just for specific articles not all of articles in a category.

the challenging part of this, is how to remove sidebars and in specific articles.

by the way I have no problem using T3 or other framework to get this working. I just need clue to handle this.

Take look at these example for better view:

normal post
http://zoomg.ir/2015/10/08/68251/introduce-prime-world-defenders/

no sidebar with full width post
http://zoomg.ir/2015/04/18/28227/samsung-galaxy-s6-review-gaming/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the helix3 framework, it's easy to manage the layout.

Essentially on the default layout you have 2 positions, left and right, at the sides of the main content (component part), so if you create a module and assign it to left position it will appear on the left sidebar reducing the content size like in your first example.

If you need just full article type and article with a sidebar (left or right no matter) this is the best solution.

By the way, you can create custom templates for your joomla articles. Inside the template folder: html/com_content/article you find the override of the default article.

You can duplicate the default.php and rename as, for example, sidebar.php. Then change the code as you prefer. In this way you'll find the new alternative template inside you administrator panel, go to your article and under the options look at the last dropdown.

Here more information: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Hope it helps,
Marco